# Передача Double через GET-запрос

Tags: java, get, double

Отправляю GET-запрос в тесте через `mockMvc`:

```
String calculateProgramsAsString = mockMvc.perform(get("/health/program/calculate/" + MEMBER_ID + "/75.5"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.header").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data").isNotEmpty())
                .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Принимающий контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/calculate/{id}/{weight}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<AppGenericEntity<BakProgramPackDto>> getPrograms(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
                                                                           @PathVariable("weight") String weight) {
```

Почему-то приходит `75.0`. При замене на `75,5` падает. При замене на `String weight` приходит `75`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20743941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась следующим образом:

Пришлось поставить слэш в конце запроса, обозначив, таким образом, границы переменной `{weight}`.

```
String calculateProgramsAsString = mockMvc.perform(get("/health/program/calculate/" + MEMBER_ID + "/75.5/"))
```

Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/calculate/{id}/{weight}/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<AppGenericEntity<BakProgramPackDto>> getPrograms(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
                                                                           @PathVariable("weight") Double weight) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно было бы домножить на 10-100 и соответственно разделить.

Comment: И написать в API: "Пришлите вес в стаграммах, а то мы не можем принять Double" :)